# Extract Title and Description from multiple URLs

Tags: php, url, title, metatag

I have a list of links that are all articles. I am trying to use PHP to extract the title and the description from all of them at once. I also want the article title to be hyperlink to the URL and the description to be displayed below it in italics.

My issue is this: it works when I do it for one link, but when I try multiple links or even if I duplicate the code and manually paste in each link, it doesn't work. Below is my code that I have that works for one link. Any ideas?

```
    <html>
    <a href="http://bit.ly/18EFx87">
    <b><?php

    function getTitle($Url){
        $str = file_get_contents($Url);
        if(strlen($str)>0){
            preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
            return $title[1];
        }
    }
    echo getTitle("http://bit.ly/18EFx87");

    ?></b><br>
    </a>
    <i><?php
    $tags = get_meta_tags('http://bit.ly/18EFx87');
    echo $tags['description'];
    ?></i>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean multiple URLs, then something like this will work. :

```
<html>

<?php
function getTitle($url){
    @$str = file_get_contents($url); // suppressing the warning
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
        return $title[1];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$urls = array('http://bit.ly/18EFx87', 'url2');
foreach($urls as $url)
{
    $title = getTitle($url);
    if($title === false)
    {
        continue;
    }
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '"><b>';
    echo $title;

    echo '</b></a><br><i>';

    $tags = get_meta_tags($url);
    echo $tags['description'] . '</i>';
 } 
 ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rasmus. I see what you're doing there, and the code makes sense - for some reason when I try it, it doesn't run or it comes up blank. Any idea why? Is that code running on your end?

Comment: Jep just tested it. Works fine. If you didn't replace 'url2' with an url it starts complaining which could cause your server to hide every output. Do you run it on apache?

Comment: Nevermind! I see you just edited the code in the foreach tag - very nice. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!